# Quantidade carrinho

Tags: c#

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar a quantidade que insiro na minha view do carrinho e salvar ela mesmo dando refresh.. Por exemplo: o cliente adicionou 8 quantidades de macarrão mas após atualizar a página essa quantidade volta ao normal que é quantidade 1;

minha actionresult no DAO:

```
public ActionResult RecarregaItensCarrinho(int id)
    {
        ProdutosDAO dao = new ProdutosDAO();
        Produto produto = dao.BuscaPorId(id);
        if (produto != null)
        {
            return Json(new { sucesso = false, resposta = "Nao tem o que atualizar" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new {  sucesso = true, produto.Quantidade }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }
```

Minha função em js no carrinhocshtml:

```
function RecarregaItensCarrinho() {
        var itens = $("#codItens").val();
        var todosItens = @qtdTotal;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'RecarregaItens',
            data: {
                itens
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.sucesso == true) {
                    $(".qtdProduto").text(@qtdTotal);






                } else {
                    alert(data.resposta);
                }

            }



        })

    }
```

Comment: A cada vez que o usuário inserir ou remover um item do carrinho, persista essa informação no servidor...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

O ideal é cada vez que o cliente adicionar você coloque este item em uma array na sessão, assim quando o cliente mudar de pagina o dado se manterá.